# How to correctly create BLL and GridView in such situation

Tags: asp.net, gridview, data-access-layer, bll

I have designed a database, in order to better demonstrate my question, I've simplified it:

```
TB: CONSULTANTS

      ID        uniqueidentifier

      NAME      NVARCHAR(30)
```

---

```
TB: EXPENSES

      ID                uniqueidentifier

      AMOUNT            money

      CONSULTANTID      uniqueidentifier
```

---

CONSULTANTID is FK from Consultants Table, simple right?

I have created a dataset with two Data Tables which are consultants and expenses

with corresponding queries such as get expenses by consultant id, etc

however, what i wanna display in grid view is:

Amount & Consultant's Name instead of Consultant Id

---

When I tried to return a data table with (ExpenseId, Amount, ConsultantName), it causes error since schema doesn't match with base data table EXPENSES (ExpenseId, Amount, ConsultantId).

**What can I do to get (ExpenseId, Amount, ConsultantName(not id)) from BLL ?**

---

Do I have to create another data table with joining two tables together?? because ASP.NET site says that's not a preferable way to create DAL and BLL

OR is that possible that I do some changes on gridview's BoundField (if that's possible, how to bind two different adapters' outputs together).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can create a Method in `DAL` that fetches data from the DB and returns you the `DataTable or DataSet` as appropriate for you.

```
Select c.id as ConsultantId,c.Name as Name,e.amount
from consultant c
inner join experses e
on c.ConsultantId=e.ConsultantId
```

Let your BAL do bussiness logic such as creating Consultant Class object Array and do validation on amount(such as amount can't be less than 0).

BAL returns Array of `Consultant` objects which you can use to bind with data control(or you can even send back the dataTable from the BAL as well.

I think Linq is using the first approach where it generates the sql script from the Linq Syntax and returns you collaction of object of particular type.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer right from ASP.NET site example

---

Before we creating BLL, we have to figure out what's gonna be needed in each Table Adapter.

Thus, in my case, I have to include consultantName column and other needed column with Expenses data table by using composite SELECT statement.

That is,

SELECT EXPENSEID, AMOUNT, CONSULTANTID, (SELECT CONSULTANTNAME FROM CONSULTANTS WHERE CONSULTANTS.CONSULTANTID=EXPENSES.CONSULTANTID) FROM EXPENSES

then we can manage to get all required data from this DAL.